# Docker webpack dev server

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server

While running webpack dev server in the docker container I get the following error message

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 192.168.99.100:8080
```

`192.168.99.100` is the IP address of the docker host that runs within Oracle Virtual Box on my Windows system.
Below is the host section in my webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    host:"192.168.99.100"
  }
```

If I don't give any host, the webpack dev server runs at `http://localhost:8080` and is not accessible when I try with `http://192.168.99.100:8080`. 
Is there any explicitly setting that I need to do for this to work?
Below is the docker file

```
FROM node:4.2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app

 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

RUN npm build
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "webserver"]
```

I'm running the container using the following command

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 mynodeimg
```

Comment: Please post the command you used to create and run the containers, and your Dockerfile if possible. You can probably try set the host to be 0.0.0.0. And you need to map the 8080 port using `docker run -p 8080:8080`

Comment: Try if `0.0.0.0` works. The docker container has an internal ip that is normally 172.x.x.x and it won't be able to listen on the external ip of Docker Toolbox, that's probably why you saw the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your server to be accessible externally, specify it like this:

```
 "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0",
```

or in webpack.config.js

```
 devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
```

webpack serve --host 0.0.0.0